# HTML Button image not displaying correctly on iOS

Tags: html, css, imagebutton

I have a simple button that I am trying to display as an image using CSS. For some reason no matter what I try it shows up as a tiny button on the screen. What am I missing?

Here is my button code:

```
<div id="do_square_payment" align="center" style="display:none;">
                            <button id="do_square_payment_btn" value="Square"></button>
                           </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
code:

    #do_square_payment_btn {
    background-image: url(../images/Square.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

I attached a screenshot as well. [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does `display: inline-block` or `display: block` work?

Comment: Why do you give the button wrapper `display: none`? Is it used for some Javascript?

Comment: @MEE no, neither of those worked.

Comment: Yeah I hide the div until ‘Credit Card - Square’ is selected from the list, then I show the button. That part seems to work fine, just the button doesn’t display correctly.